# How to get automatically total amount of number I created from table at Excel?

Tags: excel

I had to put the total amount of the object manually on top of the table as I couldn't find a way to get it automatically from the table of numbers I created. Could somebody kind-heartedly teach me how to do this automatically by simply pulling the data of the table created at Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add the total sum of each stack on top you have to use a **Custom Combination Diagram** and then add **Data Labels** and then adjust them via **Format Data Labels**.

If you need a pictured step-by-step explanation have a look [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1334-excel-add-total-to-stacked-bar-chart.html).